# What is the "final security console"?

Tags: invisible-inc

I've revealed the whole map in Invisible Inc's new final mission:

[image: Invisible Inc Final Mission Map]

What is the objective at this point? The only "console" I see is the thing that Monst3r hacked in the first place (the room in the upper left of this screenshot)

Update: Well, I guess we'll never know :/

[image: Failure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either there is a level generation bug, or you missed the room with the console. I see one unopened door in the left side of the level, in the room with two consoles.

There is a supposed to be a room with a rather hard to miss blast doors (3-4 tiles wide) and a 2x2 sized console much like special consoles in other levels (detenction center, site map missions etc.).

Comment: Of course I missed a door on the complete opposite side of the level :/